# Moving view when UITextField Keyboard gets activated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

The following problem occurs when I activate my `UITextField` (better if I just show a couple images than try toUIView`which is nested within my`UITableViewController` as the footer.

Yikes can I just delete this question. Jeez

Comment: Please review the related questions before posting yet another duplicate question.

Comment: [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) class will serve your purpose

Comment: @rmaddy ok ok jeez I got it after the 3rd downvote.

Comment: What problem occured?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you are trying to shift the entire view when the UITextField becomes the first responder (i.e. adds the keyboard to the view)? If that is the case, I would add code in the UITextField delegate method:

```
#define VIEW_TAG 12345
#define kKeyboardOffsetY 80.0f

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // get a reference to the view you want to move when editing begins
    // which can be done by setting the tag of the container view to VIEW_TAG
    UIView *containerView = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_TAG];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -kKeyboardOffsetY, containerView.frame.size.width, containerView.frame.size.height);
    }];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UIView *containerView = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:VIEW_TAG];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.frame.origin.y, containerView.frame.size.width, containerView.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

You don't have to use the 'viewWithTag' method, but simply need to get a reference to the container view, which can also be done by iterating through the subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your tableview's height when keyboard appears.

Here's an example from a project of mine.

First: listen for keyboard events:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //Be informed of keyboard
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];    
}



#pragma mark keyboard

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize size = [[userInfo objectForKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,
                              self.tableView.frame.origin.y,
                              self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                              self.tableView.frame.size.height - size.height);
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize size = [[userInfo objectForKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,
                                      self.tableView.frame.origin.y,
                                      self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                      self.tableView.frame.size.height + size.height);
}
```

Comment: You still have to add your class as an observer for keyboard events

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this, its animated so it looks good.

The keyboards height is 216px and it takes .25s for it to stop.

Here is the part from my code:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if (textField.tag == 2) {
    void (^a)(void) = ^(void){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
            RegNrView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -216, 320, 460);
        }
        completion:nil];
    };

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:a];
}
```

}

This makes the UIView and keyboard to move at the exact same time.

Comment: You should not hardcode the duration or the frame. Both could change. If the text field has an input accessory view the frame will be different. Apple provides sample code shows the proper way to do this using the proper keyboard events.